# What is the most user-friendly way to test the reverse dependencies for a package?

Tags: r, devtools

Testing reverse dependencies is a pain and I find the available implementations buggy, e.g. when I run `devtools::revdep_check()` I see

```
Reverse dependency checks for <MY PACKAGE> ==========================================================================
Saving check results in `revdep/checks/`
Saving install results in `revdep/install/`
Computing reverse dependencies... 
Installing dependencies for <MY PACKAGE> to <TEMP DIR>
Installing <MY PACKAGE> to <TEMP DIR>
Error: Command failed (1)
```

so I tried its to-be successor `revdepcheck::revdep_check()` to see

```
── INIT ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── Computing revdeps ──
Error in read.dcf(file = tmpf) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In read.dcf(file = tmpf) :
  cannot open compressed file '//C:%5CUsers%5C<MY USER NAME>%5CAppData%5CLocal%5CR-crancache%5CR-crancache%5CCache/cran/src/contrib/PACKAGES', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Could you give me any simple step-by-step procedure for testing reverse dependencies that works out-of-the-box?

Comment: This may be an issue of Windows not being supported yet. Having the same issue, will let you know if I figure something out.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320722/package-reverse-dependency-checks-especially-on-windows